# Prove that inner space is incomplete and operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let's consider the following space:

$$ X = \{f \in C^\infty [0,1]: f(0)=f(1)=0   \}$$

with an inner product given by

$$ \langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 f'(t) \overline{g'(t)}dt. $$

Moreover, let's fix $h \in C^\infty [0,1]$ and define operator $M_h:X \rightarrow X$ given by
$$M_h(f) = h(t)f(t)$$
for $f \in X$ and $t \in [0,1]$.

First question is to show that space $X$ with this inner product is not a Hilbert space (motivation being that the completion of this space is the Sobolev space $H^1_0[0,1]$). My idea was the following: I wanted to find a sequence of smooth functions similar to the bump function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function , for example given by
$$ f(t) = \begin{cases} 
\operatorname{exp}\Big(\frac{-(t-\frac{1}{2})^2}{\frac{1}{2}^2 - (t-\frac{1}{2})^2}\Big),  & t \in (0,1) \\
0, & t \in \{0,1\}
\end{cases}$$

such that the mass becomes more and more concentrated in the middle (but the area of the integral of the differences keeps being small, so it would be a Cauchy sequence), and this sequence would converge to a non-continuous (but integrable) function. Unfortunately I'm not sure if this is a reasonable approach or how to explicitly describe this, since I feel like functions from the space $X$ have very strong properties so it's hard to find a sequence "breaking" it. I would appreciate any feedback about it, if possible.

The second question is to show that operator $M_h$ is bounded. I managed to show this (I will write $h$ and $f$ instead of $h(t)$ and $f(t)$ for better clarity): denote $M = \max\{M_1, M_2\}$ where
$$ M_1 = \max_{t \in [0,1]} |h(t)|$$
$$ M_2 = \max_{t \in [0,1]} |h'(t)|.$$

Then
\begin{align} 
\Vert M_h \Vert^2 &= \Vert hf \Vert = \int_0^1 (hf)'\overline{(hf)'}dt =\int_0^1 |(hf)'|^2 \\&= \int_0^1 |h'f + hf'|^2 \leq \int_0^1 (|h|^2+|h'|^2)(|f|^2 + |f'|^ 2 )dt \\
&\leq 2M^2 \Big( \int_0^1 |f|^2 dt + \int_0^1 |f'|^2 dt \Big) \\
&=2M^2 \Big( \int_0^1 |f|^2 dt + \Vert f \Vert ^2 \Big)
\end{align}
where the first inequality comes from Cauchy-Schwartz lemma. Now, I would like to do something about the remaining integral, namely $\int_0^1 |f|^2 dt$ but here I'm stuck. Could someone share a hint if this approach makes sense, assuming my previous calculations were correct?

Thanks!

Comment: The appearence of complex conjugate in the definition of the inner product indicates that functions in this space are supposed to be complex valued. So $\|f\|^{2} =\int |f'|^{2}$ and not $\int (f')^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I changed the notation and approximation to work with complex valued functions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote $ \int_0^1 |f|^2 dt + \| f\|$ for $ \int_0^1 |f|^2 dt + \| f\|^{2}$

$f(x)=\int_0^{x} f'(t)dt$ so $|f(x)| \leq \int_0^{1}|f'(t)| dt\leq \sqrt {\int_0^{1}|f'(t)|^{2} dt}$ This implies that $\int_0^{1}|f(t)|^{2} dt \leq \int_0^{1}|f'(t)|^{2} dt=\|f\|^{2}$.

Here is a different approach to the first part. Define $T(f)=f(\frac 1 2)=\int_0^{\frac 1 2} f'(t)dt$. This is clearly a continuous linear functional. If the space is complete then we can apply Riesz Theorem to conclude that there exists $g \in X$ with $Tf=\int_0^{1}f'(t)g'(t)dt$ for all $f \in X$. Thus $\int_0^{1} f'(t)[g'(t)-\chi_{(0,\frac 1 2)}] dt=0$ for all $f \in X$. This implies that $g'(t)=\chi_{(0,\frac 1 2)}$ a.e. but this contradicts the fact that $g'$ is continuous.

Comment: I fixed the notation. Also, thank you for this approximation and this neat application of Riesz Theorem. Just a very minor thing, but is there a missing conjugate under integral when you wrote g'(t) after applying Riesz? Of course this argument still stands since then we will get that conjugate of g'(t) is this characteristic function, so we get g'(t) being this characteristic function once again, leading to contradiction.

Comment: @btfm That does not matter because if $g \in X$ then $\overline g$ is also in $X$.